# hive Drop table not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, metastore

I a new bee in hadoop world.
I created an internal table in hive and tried importing data into the same.

Then I tried to drop the table but got following error.

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDOException: Cannot join from org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping@6a9ccd9f to org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping@55eb1db2 since they have different numbers of datastore columns!
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Cannot join from org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping@6a9ccd9f to org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.PersistableMapping@55eb1db2 since they have different numbers of datastore columns!)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

What can I do to get this resolved?

any help is highly appriciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with PostgreSQL, so I've untagged it. I suggest you show your code - it might make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: My Metadata of Hive is stored in postgreSQL 
Table creation goes fine but then insertion fails as well as drop table command fails giving the above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your hive client is not matching to the metastore you are connecting to. Please provide the hive-site.xml contents, specifically the *.metastore.* related properties.

Here are the properties to look into

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>root</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>root</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```